# Capture HTTP Requests using robotframework

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework, browsermob

I am trying the automate the HTTP Requests like Google Analytics tracking made by an input url using robot framework.

I found that capture webdriver with browser mob proxy may be helpful but I am not sure on the exact steps to be followed.

Can anyone please advise on where to start to reach my goal.

Thanks in Advance,
Yams.

Comment: Yam, can you please share what have you tried?

Comment: Hi Viral Shah,  I did not start yet as I have no clue on how to start. All I did is downloaded browsermob proxy from https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy but I am not able to figure out how to start the proxy and all as I am using windows machine

Comment: So you are just trying to capture the http traffic?

Answer (score 1):

I did it by creating my own keyword.

```
Select Radio Button Otherwise    CSS_ID   True
```

This will select all radio buttons with value other than `True`.

This is my final code

```
Run My Test
    Select Radio Button    CSS_ID   True
    Correct window should popup 
    Select Radio Button Otherwise    CSS_ID   True  
    InCorrect window should popup
```

Check [Run Keyword If](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/libraries/BuiltIn.html?r=2.8.3#Run%20Keyword%20If) and [Run Keyword Unless](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/libraries/BuiltIn.html?r=2.8.3#Run%20Keyword%20Unless) keywords from the documentation.

Comment: Hi Vimal,Can you please give more details on how did you start capturing the httprequests

Comment: through `httpreq` library is available there.

Comment: Hi Vimal,Were you able to get the network traffic using httprequests library? Can you please let me know the steps or methods you used. Thanks